# Searching entire multisite post.link returns current blog url

Tags: wordpress, twig, multisite, timber

On a WordPress Multisite installation using Timber the search form returns the correct post/pages but when using {{ post.link }} the slug is prepended with the current blogs url instead of the site the page is on.

#### Example:

`Site 1:`  test.com/

Has page: foo with URL test.com/foo

`Site 2` test.com/2/

Searching for "foo"

{{post.link}} returns: test.com/2/foo. Resuting in 404.

###### How can I get the correct URL for foo when searching on site 2?

Edit

### Solution

```
// search.twig

{% for post in posts %}
  {% do fn('switch_to_blog', post.blog_id) %}

    <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
    {{post.preview}}
    <a href="{{post.link}}">Read More</a>

  {% do fn('restore_current_blog') %}
{% endfor %}


// For anyone interested here is the form using Relevanssi plugin

<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="{{site.link}}">
    <input type="text" value="{{ function('get_search_query') }}" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search..." />
    <input name="searchblogs" type="hidden" value="39, 0">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" />
</form>

// Note: If only one id is entered into the searchBlogsById form field {{ post.blog_id }} returns null.
// Add a non existing blog id '0' to get around this.
```

Comment: Maybe you can add more information about how you solved site-wide search in your WordPress installation. Do you use a plugin, or a custom solution?

Comment: @Gchtr I'm using the Relevanssi plugin for multisite search.

Comment: Okay, in that case can you place `{{ dump(post.blog_id) }}` before `{{ post.link }}` and tell me what it returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because `{{ post.link }}` gets the permalink as soon as you call it. Timber uses `get_permalink()` behind the scenes, which always use the current site.

In order to make this work, you’d have to switch sites with [`switch_to_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/) before you use `{{ post.link }}`. And after you accessed all the data you need, you can use [`restore_current_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/restore_current_blog/) to switch back to the previous site.

```
{% do fn('switch_to_blog', blog_id) %}

{{ post.link }}

{% do fn('restore_current_blog') %}
```

Apparently, you’d have to know the ID of the site the post is from. If you use a plugin to search across your multisite, it should give you a possibility to access the current blog ID.

For example, if you use [Relevanssi](https://www.relevanssi.com/) with its [Multisite Search](https://www.relevanssi.com/knowledge-base/multisite-search/) feature, then the current blog ID can be accessed through `{{ post.blog_id }}`. In that case, it would work like this:

```
{% do fn('switch_to_blog', post.blog_id) %}

{{ post.link }}

{% do fn('restore_current_blog') %}
```

Comment: That did it. Although just wrapping the {{ post.link }} alone didn't work. I had to place the switch_to_blog at the start of the for loop. Thanks

Comment: Cool, I’m glad it worked! Yes, placing `switch_to_blog()` at the start of the loop makes sense, because `{{ post.link }}` is not the only function that uses the current blog ID.